# How do I add 10 buttons to AlertDialog in Android?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am trying to create an AlertDialog with 10 Buttons
but in AlertDialog there are only 3 buttons.

Comment: you should go to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html and refer to the "Creating a Custom Layout" section

Comment: WHY??? This is worst idea! Think of the user who would have to select one of 10 buttons to press.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to create a view which contains your 10 buttons, and add it to your dialog via

```
new AlertDialog.Builder().setView( your10ButtonView )...
```

Comment: How i create View that contains 10 Buttons?

Comment: Create a xml layout with 10 `<Button>` and inflate it in your code with something like `View.inflate(this, R.layout.my_buttons, null)`, then put the result in `setView()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use CustomDialog create your own layout and use that layout in your custom AlertDialog.
Like this,

```
   private Dialog mForgetPasswordDialog;
   mForgetPasswordDialog = new Dialog(Signin.this);
    mForgetPasswordDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    mForgetPasswordDialog.setContentView(R.layout.forget_password);
    mForgetPasswordDialog.setCancelable(true);

    TextView btnOk = (Button) mForgetPasswordDialog
            .findViewById(R.id.btnOk);
    // do your stug
    mForgetPasswordDialog.show();
```